# serialize temporary into boost archive

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-serialization

The following is not possible for any boost output archive:

```
int foo(){
   return 4;
}

ar << static_cast<unsigned int>(foo());
```

Is there an alternative without out creating a local temporary `x=foo()`.

and why is the underlying archive `operator <<(T & t)` not const reference , for an output archive such that the above would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, and I think [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html) is why:

> ... To help detect such cases, output archive operators expect to be
>   passed const reference arguments.

It seems worth noting that in your example `ar << foo();` does not work either (i.e. it doesn't have to do with your cast).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

unsigned int foo(){
   return 4;
}

int main()
{
    {
    std::ofstream outputStream("someFile.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << static_cast<const int&>(foo());
    }

    std::ifstream inputStream("someFile.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);

    int readBack;
    inputArchive >> readBack;

    std::cout << "Read back: " << readBack << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```